# Python splitting columns with variable spacing

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, split

I am trying to parse a table that has columns separated by a single space and multiple spaces. I am able to use re.split to separate columns with more than 1 space but then have to re-split for columns that are separated by a single space. The below code accomplishes this by splitting columns 4 and 5 multiple times but is there a better or more efficient way to do this?

I am using the method below which seems inefficient:

My Code:

```
import re

string = '''No  Mon     Date           Time Values   colors
1   Nov     11-03-2016     23:17:52 Red   colors
2   Nov     11-03-2016     19:18:00 Yellow   colors
3   Nov     11-03-2016     19:18:18 Blue   colors
4   Oct     10-03-2016     19:22:58 Orange Green   colors
5   Oct     10-07-2016     10:37:36 Red Blue Yellow   colors
6   Oct     10-07-2016     10:37:36 White   colors
7   Sep     09-07-2016     10:37:37 Ping White Yellow Green   colors'''

for i in string.splitlines():
    col1 =re.split(r'\s{2,}', i)[0]
    col2 =re.split(r'\s{2,}', i)[1]
    col3 = re.split(r'\s{2,}', i)[2]
    col4 = re.split(r'\s{2,}', i)[3].split()[0]
    col5 = ' '.join(re.split(r'\s{2,}', i)[3].split()[1:])

    print('{:3} | {:3} | {:10} | {:10} | {:23}|'.format(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5))
```

Output:

```
No  | Mon | Date       | Time       | Values                 |
1   | Nov | 11-03-2016 | 23:17:52   | Red                    |
2   | Nov | 11-03-2016 | 19:18:00   | Yellow                 |
3   | Nov | 11-03-2016 | 19:18:18   | Blue                   |
4   | Oct | 10-03-2016 | 19:22:58   | Orange Green           |
5   | Oct | 10-07-2016 | 10:37:36   | Red Blue Yellow        |
6   | Oct | 10-07-2016 | 10:37:36   | White                  |
7   | Sep | 09-07-2016 | 10:37:37   | Ping White Yellow Green|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get 4 values in a single `split` operation first and then split 4th element using `\s{2,}`:

```
for i in string.splitlines():
    arr = re.split(r'\s+', i, 4)
    print('{:3} | {:3} | {:10} | {:10} | {:23}|'.
          format(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], re.split(r'\s{2,}', arr[4])[0]))

No  | Mon | Date       | Time       | Values                 |
1   | Nov | 11-03-2016 | 23:17:52   | Red                    |
2   | Nov | 11-03-2016 | 19:18:00   | Yellow                 |
3   | Nov | 11-03-2016 | 19:18:18   | Blue                   |
4   | Oct | 10-03-2016 | 19:22:58   | Orange Green           |
5   | Oct | 10-07-2016 | 10:37:36   | Red Blue Yellow        |
6   | Oct | 10-07-2016 | 10:37:36   | White                  |
7   | Sep | 09-07-2016 | 10:37:37   | Ping White Yellow Green|
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/jDlB0H)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes this does simplify it a little bit more and reduces the code. Thank you.